# Can we use google project without adding billing information to it?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

While using gsutil from command line its says '403 error' and asks me to add billing information for my project. When adding billing information, Google refuses debit card. I have used both visa and master card. it is refusing both of it ?
Now what can i do to run gsutil commands from command line?

Comment: You mention gsutil and tag the question with google-drive-sdk. These are unrelated as gsutil is for Cloud Storage. I've re-tagged it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in order to use any of the Cloud features you need to have billing enabled. You do get a $300 trial credit that's valid for 60 days when you sign up, so you won't get charged right away. If you're having issues adding a valid card as a payment method, you can contact billing support at https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing.